# Toggle hidden files using Automator (Mac)

Tags: macos, automator

There apparently is a way to show a "Toggle Hidden Files" button in Mac. I've followed the steps in this article to make such a button in the menu when I right click. http://www.macosxtips.co.uk/index_files/quickly-show-hidden-files.php

I've followed all the steps, but it's not working. Is the code outdated? I can imagine since the article has been out for quite some time now. The code I used in Automator is:

```
STATUS=`defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles`
if [ $STATUS == YES ]; 
then
    defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles NO
else
    defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES
fi
killall Finder
```

Here's a screenshot of what it looks like: https://puu.sh/uJLhs/2fd86c168a.png

It doesn't really do anything atm, even though I saved it.

Answer (score 0):

This code does not work for recent versions of macOS. Use this code instead:

```
STATUS=`defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles`
if [ $STATUS == 1 ]; 
then
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -boolean false
else
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -boolean true
fi
killall Finder
```

I've tested this code with the macOS 10.12.3 Sierra and followed all the steps listed in the linked article:

1. Open Automator
2. Choose the Service template
3. In the library on the left double click on "Run Shell Script".
4. Paste the code into the textbox.
5. Change the drop-down menu from "text" to "no input"
6. Save it.
7. In Finder select the service using Finder > Services.

Please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Which version of macOS/OS X are you using?

Comment: When I click "finder" and Hover over "Services" there's a greyed out text saying: "No services apply"

Comment: Which version of macOS/OS X are you using?

Comment: Sierra v 10.12.3